# Why is the read_pci_config_16 function performing bitwise and when calling inb/inw

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86, pci

To read PCI Configuration space, i need to write BDF and offset to 0xCF8h and then read the data register 0xCFCh

I am looking into linux kernel source, where the below logic is used.

In file arch/x86/pci/early.c

```
u32 read_pci_config(u8 bus, u8 slot, u8 func, u8 offset)
{
        u32 v;
        outl(0x80000000 | (bus<<16) | (slot<<11) | (func<<8) | offset, 0xcf8);
        v = inl(0xcfc);
        return v;
}

u8 read_pci_config_byte(u8 bus, u8 slot, u8 func, u8 offset)
{
        u8 v;
        outl(0x80000000 | (bus<<16) | (slot<<11) | (func<<8) | offset, 0xcf8);
        v = inb(0xcfc + (offset&3));
        return v;
}

u16 read_pci_config_16(u8 bus, u8 slot, u8 func, u8 offset)
{
        u16 v;
        outl(0x80000000 | (bus<<16) | (slot<<11) | (func<<8) | offset, 0xcf8);
        v = inw(0xcfc + (offset&2));
        return v;
}
```

Why is the bitwise AND operation performed in case of read_pci_config_8 and read_pci_config_16

```
v = inw(0xcfc + (offset&2));
```

Comment: Only the 2 lower bits of offset matter (meaning only values 0, 1, 2, 3) are valid sincea PCI config port is 32-bits (4*8). When accessing as bytes, the `&3` zeroes all the bits except the lower 2 bits limiting the port offset to 0,1,2,3. With a 16-bit read the `&2` zeroes all the bits above the first 2 bits and sets bit 0 to 0 as well. This has the effect of rounding the offset down to the nearest 16-bit offset and limiting the offset to the values 0 and 2. This is to keep port alignment on a 16-bit (2 byte) boundary. The values 0xcfc+0 and 0xcfc+2 ar both evenly divisible by 2.

Comment: Contrary to what’s written in one of the answers, this code is fine, and it’s the proper way to read from PCI config space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of I/O port CFC as a 32-bit “window” into the 32-bit PCI config register addressed by the value in port CF8. PCI allows reading 1, 2, or 4 bytes within this window. If the low two bits of the register offset are not 0, then the byte or bytes to be read are not at the base of the window, but instead require using an offset within the window to access the desired bytes. The AND operation you’re asking about adjusts the port address being read from, to select the desired bytes. Since a 16-bit read must be aligned to a multiple of 2 bytes, the adjustment must be either 0 or 2.

Answer (score -2):

That code is misguided.

You should only ever read and 32-bit dwords from IO port 0xCFC (chipset might ignore anything that isn't a 32-bit IO port read or write from this IO port); and they are IO ports and not RAM - e.g. IO port 0xCFD (or "IO port 0xCFC+1") is a completely unrelated IO port that has nothing to do with IO port 0xCFC at all.

For reference (and example code showing how to read a word correctly) see: https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Configuration_Space_Access_Mechanism_.231

*Note: If you read the PCI Local Bus spec/s carefully; technically the chipset is supposed to also support reads/writes of bytes and words from IO port 0xCFC, and IO ports 0xCFD, 0xCFE and 0xCFF; and maybe one day someone will manage to implement a chip that doesn't need many pages of errata and the risk of assuming the chipset actually complies with every tiny detail of every relevant specification will be low enough to justify the "near zero benefits" of Linux' approach.*

Comment: As you found out, CONFIG_DATA needs to decode any IO access that **falls within** a DWORD. Also the byte enables for the transaction are taken from the  processors bus (as per spec) to match the requested length. So the reading part is OK and actually spare an AND and a shift. The writing part writes to bits 0 and 1 of CONFIG_ADDRESS which seems odd but the spec doesn't prohibit so, those bit are read-only and the write is simply ignored (and that too spares an AND).

Comment: I don't mean to spam but I digged into the Linux's hystory. Here's my findings. In version 1.0 (1992) there was no PCI support, in version 1.2.13 (1995) Linux used the BIOS and had a PCI_CONFIG1_TUPPLE macro that indeed masked off bits 1:0 but it was never used.
Version 1.3.99 (1996) removed that macro but still used BIOS for PCI access.
Between versions 2.1.50 (1997) and 2.2.14 (1999) Linux added direct PCI access (I didn't pinpoint the exact version), asking the BIOS first if direct access was possible and with a routine to 
actually check if it actually was working. ...

Comment: It was **masking off** bits 1:0 but still addressed single bytes within the CONFIG_ADDRESS DWORD, fully conformand with the PCI spec that even back then are what we are using now. 
So in between then and now they removed the mask (for efficiency I guess), evidently they know what they are doing and you can still use an older kernel to boot Linux on an equally old system.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: AMD can't get the MMIO access mechanism to work without "Instructions to read from MMIO are required to take the form `mov eax/ax/al,<address>`" nonsense; Intel released 77 vulnerabilities recently (and can't even get `Jcc` to work properly); and you want to believe  "add an AND to avoid an AND and/or maybe a shift sometimes (depending on scenario and compiler optimizations)" is worth considering because of some cowboy volunteers with nothing to lose and a "worse is better" motto?